# resolving assets relative to react native bundle file outside project root

Tags: react-native, code-push, react-native-code-push

Issue(android): where to place image assets relative to js bundle file if bundle file is located outside of project root?

We have a small service where we upload JS bundles on each build. So, for example we have app `com.example`, if we want to update our app(while app review is pending in the app store) then we:

1. download JS bundle to android path `/data/data/com.example/files/bundle/android.bundle`
2. set this bundle as active via https://github.com/mauritsd/react-native-dynamic-bundle

Imagine that in the react App component we have a single image with path `star.png`.

When we activate a new bundle then star image is not shown.

I've checked the image path via https://reactnative.dev/docs/image#resolveassetsource in release build and the image uri resolves just to `star`.

So I tried the following file structures:

№1

```
data
--data
----com.example
------files
--------bundle
----------android.bundle <= dynamic bundle from remote server
----------star // <= our image
```

№2

```
data
--data
----com.example
------files
--------bundle
----------android.bundle <= dynamic bundle from remote server
----------star.png // <= our image
```

But still image is not shown if the bundle file is outside of the project root.

Questions:

1. What am I doing wrong? https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-code-push somehow managed to solve it.
2. Is ios solution the same one as for android?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bundle assets should be placed in the same folder where js bundle file lives(tested only on android).

You can always get bundle asset path via https://reactnative.dev/docs/image#resolveassetsource.

How to test:

1. Put an image `star.png` to the project root.
2. Create a react native app with the following code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  Text,
  StatusBar,
  Image
} from 'react-native';
import Star from './star.png';

const App: () => React$Node = () => {

  const r = Image.resolveAssetSource(Star);
  console.log(r);

  return (
    <>
      <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" />
      <SafeAreaView>
        <Text>TestAssetsApp</Text>
        <Image
          style={{width: 50, height: 50}}
          source={Star}
        />
      </SafeAreaView>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

3. Set bundle path in your `MainApplication.java`(my app package is called `com.testassetsapp`):

```
public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost =
      new ReactNativeHost(this) {
        @Override
        public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
          return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
        }

        @Override
        protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
          @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
          List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
          // Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for example:
          // packages.add(new MyReactNativePackage());
          return packages;
        }

        @Override
        protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
          return "index";
        }

        // Add this method
        @Override
        protected String getJSBundleFile() {
          return "/data/data/com.testassetsapp/files/android.bundle";
        }
      };
```

4. Create android JS bundle and assets via:

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android.bundle --assets-dest assets
```

5. Install debug version via:

```
cd android && ./gradlew installDebug
```

NOTICE: test only via `./gradlew installDebug` **without metro bundler running** as it always rewrites bundle path.

Now if you run the app you will get an error "Bundle not found".

6. Upload `android.bundle` file to `/data/data/com.testassetsapp/files/android.bundle`

Now if you run the app it should start. But star image is not yet displayed.

7. Upload bundle files from the `assets` folder to `/data/data/com.testassetsapp/files` so app data structure should be the following:
   [image]

Now if you restart the app star image should be displayed.